# Conformal Transformation of Torsion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, mathematical-physics

It is well known that under a conformal transformation, we have

$$\tilde{g}_{\mu \nu}=\Omega^2 g_{\mu \nu}, \; ; \tilde{w}_{\mu}=w_{\mu}-\frac{1}{\alpha} \partial_{\mu} \log(\Omega^2),$$

where $\omega_{\mu}$ is the Weyl vector, describing the non-metricity $Q_{\rho \nu \alpha}=-2 g_{\rho \nu} w_{\alpha}$. Let us consider a special case of Weyl-Cartan geometry, where we introduce torsion of the type

$$T^{a}_{bc}=\pi_{c} \delta^{a}_{b}- \pi_{b} \delta^{a}_{c},$$

for some one-form $\pi$. Does this torsion transform under conformal transformations, or is it invariant, not affected by the transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This perhaps isn't a very useful answer, but it simply depends on whether you define it to or not. Usually conformal transformations act on the metric alone, and so torsion is invariant. However, if you're working in a broader geometric setting with torsion, you may find it convenient to define a non-trivial transformation for the affine connection (and hence torsion).

In the literature, there are usually three different choices, weak, strong and compensating conformal transformations. The weak choice has torsion invariant, while the other two have non-trivial transformations (see https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0103093v1 for their formulae and a general discussion).

Comment: a short sanity check: given that the Weyl vector transforms, as presented in the question, doesn't this already imply that the connection is ont invariant either?

Comment: Yes the connection isn't invariant because it can be decomposed into parts that do and do not depend on the metric. (E.g., the Christoffel part leads to the well-known relation). The torsional part of the decomposition does not depend on the metric.

Comment: In this case, is the notion of Conformal Transformations in Iosifidis's PhD thesis https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.09643.pdf (chap 8.1.2, eqns 8.59, 8.60) different than the one I provided?  They seem to say that not only torsion is invariant, but also the connection. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: As I said before, it depends on the author's definition. A transformation of the metric of course implies a transformation of the Christoffel connection. Iosifidis is *choosing* the affine connection to be conformally invariant. But in general, it is not clear how the affine connection should transform, see for instance https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.6366

Comment: To be a bit more physical, conformal structure is essentially about preserving angles, and this leads to a transformations of the metric tensor. It doesn't really say anything about the affine connection; there is then necessarily a choice that must be made for how you want to transform the connection and related quantities. (However, it's effect on the Christoffel connection is unambiguous).